# Disable touchscreen in Android x86?

Tags: touchscreen

I'm running a triple-boot between Android, Ubuntu, and Windows. My computer has a bad touchscreen that is randomly clicking certain areas of the screen, and I want to know if it's possible to disable the touchscreen driver. I have Android set up to boot via grub2. (Note that I never attempted to install Android on the machine itself, I installed it to a USB drive on virtualbox then copied the android system folder to Ubuntu's partition, then modified my 40_custom file so I can boot Android.)

The Android version I'm running is 5.1. I installed this because Android 6 didn't seem to boot in Virtualbox so I thought it probably wouldn't boot on my PC. (Apparently it seemed to softlock on boot inside Virtualbox.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your original problem is not specific to Android, and you're making this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

What you should really do is unhook the touchscreen cable, and that solves it for all 3 operating systems.

On the laptops I've worked on, the ribbon cables for the screen are detachable from both ends: behind the LCD panel, and on the motherboard. Find out which is easiest to get to on your laptop by searching for disassembly videos, or just by removing screws until you get to it.

If this *is* an Android-specific problem for you, you'll want to take a look at `/dev/input/event0` and `event1` and `event2` and so on.

Figure out which `event` corresponds to your touchscreen by using the `getevent -i` command from a shell terminal to read the descriptions, and `getevent` without the -i to track all inputs, touches, accelerometer movements, etc. in live action to narrow down which event is touchscreen. I have not verified this, but you might be able to disable the culprit driver by changing permissions on the `eventXXXXX` file to read-only with a root file browser.

I also just found an app that seems promising: [Touch Blocker - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.argotronic.touchblocker)
But I'm 99% sure that will prevent using the mouse as well.

Comment: The question doesn't assume it is Android specific. The question asks how to fix it for Android. For example in Windows disabling the touchscreen in `devmgmt.msc` will fix it there, and an entry in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` will disable it in Linux. No messing around with hardware required. In the example of something like a Surface Pro you REALLY don't want to be opening that up to pull a cable if you don't have to.