# How to block touchscreen?

Tags: root-access, touchscreen

How can I block touchscreen? Using root permissions is acceptable. I was able to do it by removing /dev/input/event0 but recreating it with mknod does not enable touchscreen back. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You've not stated your final objective.

Comment: I need to block all input from touchscreen. How can I do it?

Comment: put a piece of perspex or glass in front of it

Comment: Related: [Disable touchscreen in Android x86](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139190/disable-touchscreen-in-android-x86/139224)